# is there a way to resize/expand the filter list in Excel?

Tags: excel

in Excel 2007, the size of drop down filter list is fixed, every time I need to drag the right bottom conor to resize/expand the filter list.

is there a way to set the size of the filter list?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately there isn't a way to adjust.